# HOW: Currency switch via URL code: ?currency=CAD and ?currency=USD

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want my Magento store to switch currency to Canadian dollars when adding ?currency=CAD suffix in the URL.
www.website.com/accessirues?currency=CAD

As well as, when adding ?currency=USD suffix in the URL, I want to switch to USD currency.
www.website.com/accessirues?currency=USD

Please someone help me out, I am trying to figure it out for several weeks and no luck.

Help very much appreciated!

Comment: Solution posted on other topic, doesnt work. Tried.

Comment: Honestly, I cant get it working. Only on default site. I spend soo much time trying to figure it out, maybe fix something, and gave up...
The extension does what I need, but cant get it working :(